# fit background header image

Tags: css, image, header, background-image

I have image in header section but not the whole image is showing on full screen.

See below images please:

[Full browser windows screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKhWb.jpg)

The image gets fit without any cut if I resize the window to lower like this:

[Image on resizing window size smaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlxxl.jpg)

I want the image to fit in full screen without any cut like it gets when we smaller the browser window size. Thanks!!

Code:

```
<!-- Header Section START-->
<div class="header">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <h2 style="padding-left:10px;color:white;">Online Video Gallery <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-film fa-lg" style="color:black;"></span></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-3">
        <p style="margin-top:20px;">    <input type="text" name="search_box" placeholder="Search here">&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="search_btn" value="Search"></p>
    </div>
</div>
</div> <!-- Header END-->
```

**CSS .header class code:**

```
.header {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image: url(/image/header.jpg);
background-size: cover;
border-radius:4px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `bacground-size:cover;`.

If it does not work, set width of your image to 100%. Like: `width:100%;`

Comment: Tried. I edited the post with code, please do check and correct me. Thanks

Comment: I guess there are some unnecessary padding and margin. Set them to zero.  `.heading {padding:0; margin:0;}` Remove background-size property. If still it does not work add universal selector. Like this:  `*{padding:0; margin:0;}`

Comment: still doesn't work and if I remove the background-size that it doesn't fit to 100% width. I display in like only 90% width.

Comment: Universal selector working fine. Check this: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/pq47ewa3/).

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, put your _row div_ with in another _new div_ with **container-fluid** class.

Comment: I already have div container-fluid class but that was before header class start so I had just included header part coding.

Comment: The image still looks the same there. please check the image on post on smaller window and understand I want the image to look same with that full light image on full screen

Comment: Try to give height of your background image in pixels rather than percentage. It might work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try width 100% in CSS. Are you using bootstrap or another framework that's similar?

Comment: I'm using bootstrap. I tried width:100%; already. I have edited the post with code please check.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the height and padding of the row will display the image properly. Try this snippet.

```
 <div class="header">
 <div class="row" style="background-color:black;height:120px;padding:15px;">
 <div class="col-md-5" >
 <h2 style="padding-left:10px;color:white">Online Video Gallery <span 
 class="glyphicon glyphicon-film fa-lg" style="color:black;"></span></h2>
</div>
<div class="col-md-offset-4 col-sm-3">
    <p style="margin-top:20px;">    <input type="text" name="search_box"
    placeholder="Search here">&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="search_btn"
value="Search"></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't help. It still looks like this : http://imgur.com/32ShToI and this is how I want the image to be displayed on full window screen : http://imgur.com/3L0UHCN

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue too but when I set my body margin to 0 (css code), everything solved.

```
header {
    background-color: #04082E
}
body {
    background-color: #447695;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#447695,#359D93,#BFE6EF);
    color: #EEBD6B;
    min-height: 100vh;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    margin: 0
}
```

This is my sample code if you want to refer. There will be the same output as the class .header you defined in html. In my case, my html code I just go with header tag.

```
<header>
    <img class="logo" src="img/VL logo.png" />
</header>
```